# OAuth callback on android

Tags: android, android-studio, oauth-2.0

I am working with the Destiny 2 API, and my application requires OAuth(2.0). To grant the authorization for my app I create an intent which takes the user to the browser where they are supposed to grant permission, everything up until this point works fine. My problem here is the redirect to the application as soon as the authorization is granted. For the Destiny 2 API the redirect link is setup in the developers portal, my redirect link (URI) is: 'DestinyData://callback'

As soon as the authorization is granted it continues in the browser (with an error 404) and never hits the onresume inside my application. I have done plenty of research on this topic, but just cant seem to figure it out(probably just missing something).

Here is the manifest code:

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

     <data
         android:host="callback"
         android:scheme="DestinyData" />
</intent-filter>
```

Here is the authorization link:

```
BASE_OAUTH_URL + "?client_id=" + CLIENT_ID +
                    "&response_type=code&redirect_uri=" + REDIRECT_URI
```